# Convert python literal_eval string to hy

Tags: hy

I would like to convert the following to Hy, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it; is there perhaps a way to convert a string of python code to the hy syntax? I don't know if `py` would work because the evaluated result of `f_back` may not be safe.

```py
import ast, inspect
def test(f_back):
    return ast.literal_eval(f"inspect.currentframe(){'.f_back' * f_back}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always evaluate `x = x.f_back` repeatedly in a loop instead of using metaprogramming for this.

To address the more general question, Hy itself only implements the Hy-to-Python direction, not Python to Hy. There's Hikaru Ikuta's [py2hy](https://github.com/woodrush/py2hy), which doesn't work with recent releases of Hy, but [he's recently talked about updating it](https://github.com/hylang/hy/issues/1721#issuecomment-1017477821), so that may change soon.

Comment: Right, right; I remember that discussion. Then I guess I'll use the loop; thanks!